# Can I use AVAudioEngine to read from a file, process with an audio unit and write to a file, faster than real-time?

Tags: ios, audiounit, avaudioengine

I am working on an iOS app that uses AVAudioEngine for various things, including recording audio to a file, applying effects to that audio using audio units, and playing back the audio with the effect applied. I use a tap to also write the output to a file. When this is done it writes to the file in real time as the audio is playing back.

Is it possible to set up an AVAudioEngine graph that reads from a file, processes the sound with an audio unit, and outputs to a file, but faster than real time (ie., as fast as the hardware can process it)? The use case for this would be to output a few minutes of audio with effects applied, and I certainly wouldn't want to wait for a few minutes for it to be processed.

**Edit:** here's the code that I'm using to set up the AVAudioEngine's graph, and play a sound file:

```
AVAudioEngine* engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];

AVAudioPlayerNode* player = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
[engine attachNode:player];

self.player = player;
self.engine = engine;

if (!self.distortionEffect) {
    self.distortionEffect = [[AVAudioUnitDistortion alloc] init];
    [self.engine attachNode:self.distortionEffect];
    [self.engine connect:self.player to:self.distortionEffect format:[self.distortionEffect outputFormatForBus:0]];
    AVAudioMixerNode* mixer = [self.engine mainMixerNode];
    [self.engine connect:self.distortionEffect to:mixer format:[mixer outputFormatForBus:0]];
}

[self.distortionEffect loadFactoryPreset:AVAudioUnitDistortionPresetDrumsBitBrush];

NSError* error;
if (![self.engine startAndReturnError:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
} else {
    NSURL* fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"test2" withExtension:@"mp3"];
    AVAudioFile* file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:fileURL error:&error];

    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
    } else {
        [self.player scheduleFile:file atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
        [self.player play];
    }
}
```

The above code plays the sound in the test2.mp3 file, with the `AVAudioUnitDistortionPresetDrumsBitBrush` distortion preset applied, in real time.

I then modified the above code by adding these lines after [self.player play]:

```
        [self.engine stop];
        [self renderAudioAndWriteToFile];
```

I modified the renderAudioAndWriteToFile method that Vladimir provided so that instead of allocating a new AVAudioEngine in the first line, it simply uses self.engine that has already been set up.

However, in renderAudioAndWriteToFile, it's logging "Can not render audio unit" because AudioUnitRender is returning a status of `kAudioUnitErr_Uninitialized`.

**Edit 2**: I should mention that I'm perfectly happy to convert the AVAudioEngine code I posted to use the C apis if that would make things easier. However, I would want the code to produce the same output as the AVAudioEngine code (including the use of the factory preset shown above).

Answer (score 15):

1. Configure your engine and player node.
2. Call `play` method for your player node.
3. Pause your engine.
4. Get an audio unit from your AVAudioOutputNode (`audioEngine.outputNode`)
   with this [method](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioIONode_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/AVAudioIONode/audioUnit).
5. Render from audio unit with [AudioUnitRender](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioUnitRender) in cycle and write audio buffer list to file with [Extended Audio File Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MusicAudio/Reference/ExtendedAudioFileServicesReference/).

Example:

Audio engine configuration

```
- (void)configureAudioEngine {
    self.engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
    self.playerNode = [[AVAudioPlayerNode alloc] init];
    [self.engine attachNode:self.playerNode];
    AVAudioUnitDistortion *distortionEffect = [[AVAudioUnitDistortion alloc] init];
    [self.engine attachNode:distortionEffect];
    [self.engine connect:self.playerNode to:distortionEffect format:[distortionEffect outputFormatForBus:0]];
    self.mixer = [self.engine mainMixerNode];
    [self.engine connect:distortionEffect to:self.mixer format:[self.mixer outputFormatForBus:0]];
    [distortionEffect loadFactoryPreset:AVAudioUnitDistortionPresetDrumsBitBrush];
    NSError* error;
    if (![self.engine startAndReturnError:&error])
        NSLog(@"Can't start engine: %@", error);
    else
        [self scheduleFileToPlay];
}

- (void)scheduleFileToPlay {
    NSError* error;
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"filename" withExtension:@"m4a"];
    self.file = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:fileURL error:&error];
    if (self.file)
        [self.playerNode scheduleFile:self.file atTime:nil completionHandler:nil];
    else
        NSLog(@"Can't read file: %@", error);
}
```

Rendering methods

```
- (void)renderAudioAndWriteToFile {
    [self.playerNode play];
    [self.engine pause];
    AVAudioOutputNode *outputNode = self.engine.outputNode;
    AudioStreamBasicDescription const *audioDescription = [outputNode outputFormatForBus:0].streamDescription;
    NSString *path = [self filePath];
    ExtAudioFileRef audioFile = [self createAndSetupExtAudioFileWithASBD:audioDescription andFilePath:path];
    if (!audioFile)
        return;
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:self.file.url];
    NSTimeInterval duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(asset.duration);
    NSUInteger lengthInFrames = duration * audioDescription->mSampleRate;
    const NSUInteger kBufferLength = 4096;
    AudioBufferList *bufferList = AEAllocateAndInitAudioBufferList(*audioDescription, kBufferLength);
    AudioTimeStamp timeStamp;
    memset (&timeStamp, 0, sizeof(timeStamp));
    timeStamp.mFlags = kAudioTimeStampSampleTimeValid;
    OSStatus status = noErr;
    for (NSUInteger i = kBufferLength; i < lengthInFrames; i += kBufferLength) {
        status = [self renderToBufferList:bufferList writeToFile:audioFile bufferLength:kBufferLength timeStamp:&timeStamp];
        if (status != noErr)
            break;
    }
    if (status == noErr && timeStamp.mSampleTime < lengthInFrames) {
        NSUInteger restBufferLength = (NSUInteger) (lengthInFrames - timeStamp.mSampleTime);
        AudioBufferList *restBufferList = AEAllocateAndInitAudioBufferList(*audioDescription, restBufferLength);
        status = [self renderToBufferList:restBufferList writeToFile:audioFile bufferLength:restBufferLength timeStamp:&timeStamp];
        AEFreeAudioBufferList(restBufferList);
    }
    AEFreeAudioBufferList(bufferList);
    ExtAudioFileDispose(audioFile);
    if (status != noErr)
        NSLog(@"An error has occurred");
    else
        NSLog(@"Finished writing to file at path: %@", path);
}

- (NSString *)filePath {
    NSArray *documentsFolders =
            NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.m4a", [[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]];
    NSString *path = [documentsFolders[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    return path;
}

- (ExtAudioFileRef)createAndSetupExtAudioFileWithASBD:(AudioStreamBasicDescription const *)audioDescription
                                          andFilePath:(NSString *)path {
    AudioStreamBasicDescription destinationFormat;
    memset(&destinationFormat, 0, sizeof(destinationFormat));
    destinationFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = audioDescription->mChannelsPerFrame;
    destinationFormat.mSampleRate = audioDescription->mSampleRate;
    destinationFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC;
    ExtAudioFileRef audioFile;
    OSStatus status = ExtAudioFileCreateWithURL(
            (__bridge CFURLRef) [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path],
            kAudioFileM4AType,
            &destinationFormat,
            NULL,
            kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
            &audioFile
    );
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Can not create ext audio file");
        return nil;
    }
    UInt32 codecManufacturer = kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer;
    status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(
            audioFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer, sizeof(UInt32), &codecManufacturer
    );
    status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(
            audioFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription), audioDescription
    );
    status = ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(audioFile, 0, NULL);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Can not setup ext audio file");
        return nil;
    }
    return audioFile;
}

- (OSStatus)renderToBufferList:(AudioBufferList *)bufferList
                   writeToFile:(ExtAudioFileRef)audioFile
                  bufferLength:(NSUInteger)bufferLength
                     timeStamp:(AudioTimeStamp *)timeStamp {
    [self clearBufferList:bufferList];
    AudioUnit outputUnit = self.engine.outputNode.audioUnit;
    OSStatus status = AudioUnitRender(outputUnit, 0, timeStamp, 0, bufferLength, bufferList);
    if (status != noErr) {
        NSLog(@"Can not render audio unit");
        return status;
    }
    timeStamp->mSampleTime += bufferLength;
    status = ExtAudioFileWrite(audioFile, bufferLength, bufferList);
    if (status != noErr)
        NSLog(@"Can not write audio to file");
    return status;
}

- (void)clearBufferList:(AudioBufferList *)bufferList {
    for (int bufferIndex = 0; bufferIndex < bufferList->mNumberBuffers; bufferIndex++) {
        memset(bufferList->mBuffers[bufferIndex].mData, 0, bufferList->mBuffers[bufferIndex].mDataByteSize);
    }
}
```

I used some functions from [this](http://theamazingaudioengine.com/) cool framework:

```
AudioBufferList *AEAllocateAndInitAudioBufferList(AudioStreamBasicDescription audioFormat, int frameCount) {
    int numberOfBuffers = audioFormat.mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved ? audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame : 1;
    int channelsPerBuffer = audioFormat.mFormatFlags & kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved ? 1 : audioFormat.mChannelsPerFrame;
    int bytesPerBuffer = audioFormat.mBytesPerFrame * frameCount;
    AudioBufferList *audio = malloc(sizeof(AudioBufferList) + (numberOfBuffers-1)*sizeof(AudioBuffer));
    if ( !audio ) {
        return NULL;
    }
    audio->mNumberBuffers = numberOfBuffers;
    for ( int i=0; i<numberOfBuffers; i++ ) {
        if ( bytesPerBuffer > 0 ) {
            audio->mBuffers[i].mData = calloc(bytesPerBuffer, 1);
            if ( !audio->mBuffers[i].mData ) {
                for ( int j=0; j<i; j++ ) free(audio->mBuffers[j].mData);
                free(audio);
                return NULL;
            }
        } else {
            audio->mBuffers[i].mData = NULL;
        }
        audio->mBuffers[i].mDataByteSize = bytesPerBuffer;
        audio->mBuffers[i].mNumberChannels = channelsPerBuffer;
    }
    return audio;
}

void AEFreeAudioBufferList(AudioBufferList *bufferList ) {
    for ( int i=0; i<bufferList->mNumberBuffers; i++ ) {
        if ( bufferList->mBuffers[i].mData ) free(bufferList->mBuffers[i].mData);
    }
    free(bufferList);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice Vladimir. Unfortunately this code is outputting the message "Can not render audio unit", as the status returned by AudioUnitRender is kAudioUnitErr_Uninitialized. I'll add some code to my question to show how I'm setting up the AVAudioEngine's graph before executing the code you provided.

Comment: This code just shows you my idea. Unfortunately I can't test it with your configuration. I used a big part of this code in my project exactly for things you are asking. But I worked with Core Audio and AUGraph, not with AVAudioEngine. I sure it will work if you configure your engine right.

Comment: OK, thanks again Vladimir. I'm happy to switch to using Core Audio and AUGraph, but I'm less familiar with these APIs. I've added a bounty to the question and will happily award it if you can show me how to adapt my existing code to use Core Audio and AUGraph instead of AVAudioEngine.

Comment: I tried your code and fix an issue. Take a look https://github.com/VladimirKravchenko/AVAudioEngineOfflineRender

Comment: This is great - thanks very much Vladimir! Just one problem I've noticed - for at least one of my input files, the resulting output file ends about 2 seconds early. Any idea why that would be? I can post a link to the input file if you like.

Comment: what is the sample rate of this file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80197/discussion-between-greg-and-vladimir-kravchenko).

Comment: I dowloaded, built and ran the demo.  The resulting file was 40 seconds of silence.  I'll try to figure out why, but wanted to give you a heads-up.

Comment: mahboudz, what device or simulator did you use? I tested it with my iphone 6 and simulators on 2 different machines and this code worked.

Comment: I tested on
iPhone 6, iOS 8.3.
Simulator iPad Air 8.3
iPhone 5: iOS 8.3
iPod Touch: iOS 8.3

Doesn't seem to have a pattern.  The silence can be the entire output file, or just the first ~5 seconds, or after ~5 seconds of audio then silence.  I can send you the sound files if you want.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'll try to reproduce and fix this problem. Did you use my sample project https://github.com/VladimirKravchenko/AVAudioEngineOfflineRender without any changes?

Comment: Yes.  (Sorry for delay.  Traveling.  I can try to debug once I am home)

Comment: I can confirm the same issue @mahboudz mentioned with the the silence at the beginning of the output file on iPhone 6, iOS8.3 and 8.2 simulators.

Comment: I have the same issue with @mahboudz. It's almost 6 second silence in the output file. I tested the project in github with Simulator 9.1

Comment: I've posted a related question about how this approach gives me a silent output if headphones are connected http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34144456/avaudioengine-offline-render-silent-output-only-when-headphones-connected

Comment: This is great! Any ideas how one might make this work with a MIDI file using AVAudioSequencer (or MusicPlayer)? I made a quick prototype that successfully produces an audio file when rendered offline, but it sounds as if all the MIDI events are triggered at once: https://github.com/archagon/aumidisynth-offline-render-test

Comment: I tried recording an audio (via `AVRecorder`) and tried loading it, but after rendering, the output file is silent and 0 seconds long. Any clue guys?

Comment: When my duration is not a whole number for example 15.000090702947846 because I am recording the audio, I get a blank in between. Raised an issue with the cause of having blanks in between at https://github.com/VladimirKravchenko/AVAudioEngineOfflineRender/issues/5

Comment: HI . 
Ive tried this , it doesn't work on iphones 7 , 7+ , it gives me a silenced file

Comment: How is this different from AVAudioEngine's manual rendering mode?