# kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer analogue for os x

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-audio, audiounit, avaudioengine

So i trying save my audio using this [method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679061/can-i-use-avaudioengine-to-read-from-a-file-process-with-an-audio-unit-and-writ). But I need it on os x. In [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30679061/can-i-use-avaudioengine-to-read-from-a-file-process-with-an-audio-unit-and-writ) men use:

```
UInt32 codecManufacturer = kAppleSoftwareAudioCodecManufacturer;
status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(
        audioFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_CodecManufacturer, sizeof(UInt32), &codecManufacturer
);
status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(
        audioFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription), audioDescription
);
status = ExtAudioFileWriteAsync(audioFile, 0, NULL);
```

It's working only if i will use IPHONE. So I try to find analogue on OS X. I have this code, that not working:

```
UInt32 codecManufacturer2 = kAudioDecoderComponentType;

status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(audioFile, kAudioFormatProperty_Decoders, sizeof(UInt32), &codecManufacturer2);

status = ExtAudioFileSetProperty(audioFile, kExtAudioFileProperty_ClientDataFormat, sizeof(AudioStreamBasicDescription), audioDescription);
status = ExtAudioFileWriteAsync (audioFile, 0, NULL);
```

So what's wrong?

Comment: What is not working about this?  If you look at the "`status`" returned by each function, does it always come back as `noErr` for each line that is called?

Comment: So it write : _Can not render audio unit_

Comment: Total i get a new file. It has only header. But it dont has any information, only header.

Comment: @Ray, did you find the solution?