# Save Audio File after apply Filter(AVAudioUnitEQ) and finally save it as mp3?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioengine, ezaudio, avaudiofile

I am so Frustrating to save the Audio File After Apply the Filter. The filter only applicable for the AVAudioPlayerNode which mean during Playing in the player the filter is perfect to apply but how can i save this ? I am so struggle last 3 days, Please any help will be appreciate. 
 These below codes are i used,

engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];

```
 - (void)setupEQ
{
      NSLog(@"setupEQ");

      unitEq = [[AVAudioUnitEQ alloc] initWithNumberOfBands:12];
      unitEq.globalGain = 3.0;
      AVAudioUnitEQFilterParameters *filterParameters;
      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[0];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 31;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain = [[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_31.5hz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[1];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 63;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain = [[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_63hz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[2];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 125;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain = [[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_125hz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[3];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 250;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain = [[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_250hz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[4];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 500;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain = [[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_500hz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[5];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 1000;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain = [[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_1khz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[6];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 2000;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain = [[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_2khz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[7];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 4000;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain =[[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_4khz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[8];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 8000;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain = [[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_8khz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[9];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeParametric;
      filterParameters.frequency = 16000;
      filterParameters.bandwidth = 1.0;
      filterParameters.gain =[[[filter_arr objectAtIndex:index_filter] objectForKey:@"filter_freq_16khz"] floatValue];
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;


      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[10];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeLowPass;
      filterParameters.frequency = 16857;
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      filterParameters = unitEq.bands[11];
      filterParameters.filterType = AVAudioUnitEQFilterTypeHighPass;
      filterParameters.frequency = 205;
      filterParameters.bypass = FALSE;

      [engine attachNode:unitEq];
}







audioFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForReading:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self audio_file_path:mp3FileName]]] error:&playerError];
            [self setupPlayer];
            [self setupEQ];

            AVAudioMixerNode *mixerNode = [engine mainMixerNode];
            [engine connect:audio_player_node to:unitEq format:audio_file.processingFormat];
            [engine connect:unitEq to:mixerNode format:audio_file.processingFormat];
```

These are samples it works fine. But how can i store the audio file with this same frequencies? and the audio file should be in mp3 format. In apple they only target the saving file as m4a.

Comment: I got answer from this link which i share the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660501/save-the-audio-file-in-the-background/35739362#35739362

Answer (score 0):

try this, when you play the file, and you have to play the whole file again to get the effect saved.

```
AVAudioFormat  * commonFormat = [[AVAudioFormat alloc] initWithCommonFormat:AVAudioPCMFormatFloat32 sampleRate:44100 channels:2 interleaved:NO];


AVAudioFile *outputFile = [[AVAudioFile alloc] initForWriting:[NSURL URLWithString:[self filePath1]] settings:commonFormat.settings error:&error];


[unitEq  installTapOnBus:0 bufferSize:4096 format:commonFormat block:^(AVAudioPCMBuffer *buffer, AVAudioTime *when)
 {

     if (outputFile.length < file.length)
     {//Let us know when to stop saving the file, otherwise saving infinitely
         NSError *error;

         NSAssert([outputFile writeFromBuffer:buffer error:&error], @"error writing buffer data to file, %@", [error localizedDescription]);

     }else{
         audioEngine = nil;
         [unitEq removeTapOnBus:0];//if we dont remove it, will keep on tapping infinitely

     }

 }
];
```

Comment: I tried this before but nothing execute after the installTapOnBus with no response. Let me try again.

Comment: Instead of `mixerNode` try `unitEq `

Comment: K friend Let me check..

Comment: Nope. It doesn't work. I will update the issue Please check it out and let me know the issue..